# Why isn't my Silverlight Datagrid Delete Button firing the event?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I have datagrid with a delete button XAML looks like:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Del/Tgl" >
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Delete" 
           Command="{Binding DeleteRowCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Column}"
                    />
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I implemented ICommand as DelegateCommand by copying the code from John Papa. I added a public property to my ViewModel :

```
public ICommand DeleteRowCommand {get;set;}
```

In the constructor of my viewModel I set the command:

```
this.DeleteRowCommand = new DelegateCommand(onDelete, CanDelete);
```

and finally defined the `onDelete`, and `CanDelete`:

```
private void onDelete(object param)
{
    // Get the Column Name
    string strColumnName = param as string ?? string.Empty;
}

private bool CanDelete(object param)
{
    // If we ae here we can delete the row
    return true;
}
```

Everything works on my Silvelight grid but the delete button click, and I never go to `onDelete` function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Basically Command binding will look for DeleteRowCommand property inside the Object ( I mean the list of object that is binded as ItemSource to the datagrid). So you need to set the Source of Binding or use relativesource if you are using SL5.

Comment: Thank you vino that was the problem. I just changed the binding to:
Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}, Path= DeleteRowCommand}" and now is working. Could you add your comment as answer in order for me to accept the answer,and give you a Point. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Command binding will look for DeleteRowCommand property inside the Object ( I mean the list of object that is binded as ItemSource to the datagrid). So you need to set the Source of Binding or use relativesource if you are using SL5.

Cheers!
Vinod